# Adding Vagrant to an existing VirtualBox Machine

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Is there anyway to add Vagrant on an existing VM without turning the VM into a box and importing it? I have a VM I use extensively that I'd like to add vagrant onto for running it for quick code compiles without having to launch the VM in full, but I can't see a way without doing it as a box creation.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid generating a Vagrant box? You can still use the box then the same way you did use your existing Virtualbox VM.

Answer (score 1):

No, the way you add an existing VirtualBox VM is by creating a box from it.